# C++ loading Matrix from file and Construct

Tags: c++, file-io, constructor

I am creating a program where to get a matrix, the function calls *matrixname*.loadMatrix() and then works with it from there. However, I'm getting tripped up by my constructor. I have:

Constructor:

```
Matrix Matrix(int row, int col){

int v;

for(int i=0; i<row; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<col; j++){
        fin >>v;
        M.setElement(i, j, v);
    }
}
}
```

and the function loadMatrix:

```
Matrix Test::loadMatrix(std::string filename){
std::ifstream fin(filename);

int r;
int c;

fin >>r;
fin >>c;

return Matrix M(r, c);

}
```

My question is should I be doing all the *fin >>* within the constructor? Or is this going to work? I can't compile and do trial and error right now because I'm working off my tablet while my computer is out of commission.

Answer (score 0):

fin is local in the function loadMatrix.. it's undefined in the Matrix constructor

Answer (score 0):

*fin* is declared within the scope of your Matrix constructor, so that is not the way to do it.

Could you not read in all of your ints into a 1D array, and then pass the array by reference to the Matrix as its internal data? How you view the data is up to you, but the two approaches are called **row major** and **column major**

An example of row major storage of a 2x3 matrix, taken from wikipedia is

```
  int[6] = {0,1,2,3,4,5}
            ^     ^
```

where each new row corresponds to every 3rd element.

column major storage of the same would be

```
  int[6] = {0,3,1,4,2,5}
            ^   ^   ^
```

where every 2nd element corresponds to a column.